# Using Test::Unit in an abstraction layer

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, testunit, pageobjects

Is there a way to call assertions from inside an object?  I am writing Selenium tests and using test unit for assertions and easy reporting.  I have an abstraction layer between the top level test ( class that extends Test::Unit::TestCase)  and selenium webdriver.  I have my abstraction layer responsible for all items on the page and I need a way for the top level test to stop if the abstraction layer finds something other than it was expecting.  If I could call a Test::Unit assertion from inside this abstraction layer that would be ideal.  If there are any suggestions about how to better accomplish this I am open to suggestions. 
Thanks, 
Zach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the Test::Unit assertions from within the abstraction layer by including the `Test::Unit::Assertions` module.

So your code could look something like:

```
require 'test/unit'

class MyPageObject
    include Test::Unit::Assertions

    def initialize()
        assert(false, 'abstraction layer found something wrong')
    end
end

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_1()
        page = MyPageObject.new
        assert(false, 'test found something wrong')
    end
end
```

The `include Test::Unit::Assertions` line would give your MyPageObject class (I believe this is what you are calling the abstraction layer) access to the Test::Unit assertions.

In the above example, the assertion within the MyPageObject class would fail, causing the test_1 to fail.

The only problem I have had with using this solution was with the reporting of the number of assertions done (seen at the end of the Test::Unit report). The number does not include the assertions made in the abstraction layer. However, I have not seen enough value in that number to be worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I observed the same lack of reporting of the number of assertions.  That's alright for my purposes though.  Your solution works great!